# How to specify file path in Java Bean in a web application?

Tags: java, managed-bean

I want to read **models.txt** in WebContent/resources/db/ from **IndexBean.java** in src/DataTable/. How shall I set the filePath in

```
sc = new Scanner(new File(filePath));
```

I know I can achieve this by absolute path, but want to know how to do it in relative path.

[image: capture]

And another interesting thing is:
In **IndexBean.java** which **is a Java Bean**, if I run the following code, I will get the path of eclipse.exe. While if I run the same code in **testFileRead.java** in the same package which **is not a Java Bean**, I will get the path of the workspace of the application. Could someone explain this? Thanks!

```
File dir1 = new File("..");
try {
    System.out.println("Current dir : " + dir1.getCanonicalPath());
} catch (IOException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: This question is not related with Eclipse nor JSF nor JavaBeans. Again, if you're working with Managed Beans, **call them like that**, not as java beans.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, these kind of internal files should reside in an inaccessible spot, in `WebContent/WEB-INF`.

You could get a file system File:

```
File file = request.getServletContext().getRealPath("/resources/db/models.txt");
```

If you store the file as real *resource* (in the class path), you can use:

```
InputStream in = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/db/models.txt");
```

Please specify the character encoding:

```
sc = new Scanner(new File(filePath), "UTF-8");
```

So the same encoding is used whether developing under Windows or deploying on a Linux server. Because the default encoding is platform dependent.

---

```
ServletContext servletContext = (ServletContext)
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getContext();
```

Comment: So I should move the resources folder under WEB-INF? Why?... Thanks!

Comment: I guess I should declare request as HttpServletRequest and it should be String filePath(instead of File file) = request.getServletContext().getRealPath("/resources/db/models.txt");?

Comment: Right. ServletRequest may be cast to HttpServletRequest.

Comment: Added how to retrieve the ServletContext from JSF.

Answer (score 0):

I think @Joop Eggen has proposed the best solution for you. However, sometimes you can set a environment variable to your file path and you can change it as you push your code through different environment.

```
 String dir = System.getProperty("user.dir");
```

Comment: Especially sensible for dynamic data, files you write to. Then you can deploy a .war without the file. Or massive file uploads.